# Dart, Flutter, Future Builder, ListViewBuilder

Tags: flutter, listview, setstate, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a response from api, it have 83 objects, but my app dont render more than 39 items with error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`, if i replace itemCount to 39 works fine, where i have mistake? Maybe its because of I'm using setState in initState? i cant show more code cause forum block it My code Here:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      loadFuture = NetworkUtils.getOrdersByUserId(id);
      NetworkUtils.getOrdersByUserId(id).then((value) {
        setState(() {
          orders = value;
        });
      });
    });
  }
class _OrderPageState extends State<OrderPage> {
  var orders = [];
  Future loadFuture;
  Timer timer;
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
              future: loadFuture,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData &&
                    snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: orders.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        margin:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 6),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              offset: Offset(0, 1),
                              blurRadius: 3,
                              color: Color(0xFF12153D).withOpacity(0.2),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        
                          child: Text('Here more info ')
                          
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  //
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[if itemsCount = orders.length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Ux.png)

[if itemsCount = 39](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJd5P.jpg)

Comment: on your `initState`, you should await your `Future`

Comment: no, `initState` can't `await`, it must be sync function

Answer (score 0):

You're performing the query twice.

1. `loadFuture = NetworkUtils.getOrdersByUserId(id);`
2. `NetworkUtils.getOrdersByUserId(id).then((value) {});`

Change it like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      loadFuture = NetworkUtils.getOrdersByUserId(id);
      loadFuture.then((value) {
        setState(() {
          orders = value;
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: i got it, but my problem is still exists(((

Comment: it must be something wrong with `NetworkUtils.getOrdersByUserId(id)`

Comment: ```static dynamic getOrdersByUserId(id) async {
    var uri = host + orders + id;
    try {
      final response =
          await Dio().get(uri).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10), onTimeout: () {
        return null;
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }``` this is my getting data function, in another page same functions works fine

Comment: Its correct, i have response data, all okay with it, but my builder cant render that